# IBM Domino: Merge NotesDocument From Two Databases

Tags: lotus-domino

I'm working on a function to union documents from two databases (normal database and archive database, the structures are same). I tried this code

```
Set result = db.CreateDocumentCollection
Call result.AddDocument(doc) 'doc is from another database
```

but there is an error "Error 4427: Document is from a different database". And I saw `notesDocumentCollection.Merge` also needs the documents to be in the same database. Is there any way to merge documents from two databases?

Comment: When you say "merge", do you mean that you want to build a NotesDocumentCollection with documents from two different databases? 
What is the ultimate goal with your code?

Comment: Yes. For the database is slow, I have to move cancelled document to archive database. So normal documents are in normal database, and  cancelled documents are in archive database. I'm trying to generate a report to show both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A NotesDocumentCollection object has a Parent property, which is a NotesDatabase. Internally, it is just a list of NoteIDs representing NotesDocument objects. Since NoteIds are not unique across databases, those NoteDocument objects have to be from the same NotesDatabase. The same thing is true for the NotesNoteCollection, too. If you need a collection that includes NotesDocuments from multiple databases, you're going to have to build your own class for that.